# Global Mouse Moved Events in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, mouse, macos-carbon, nsnotifications, mousemove

Is there a way to register for global mouse moved events in Cocoa? I was able to register for the events using Carbon's `InstallEventHandler()`, but would prefer a Cocoa equivalent. I have looked for `NSNotificationCenter` events, but there doesn't seem to be any public event names (are there private ones?)

Alternatively, is there a way to use `NSTrackingArea` for views with a `clearColor` background?

The app is Snow Leopard only.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In SnowLeopard there is a new class method on `NSEvent` which does exactly what you want: `+ (id)addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask handler:(void (^)(NSEvent*))block`. You’ll want `mask = NSMouseMovedMask`.

Comment: Cocoa documentation: [`+ addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535472-addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchin)

Answer (score 12):

A similar question was already asked on StackOverflow:
[How to make a transparent NSView subclass handle mouse events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435685/how-to-make-a-transparent-nsview-subclass-handle-mouse-events/436153#436153)

To summarize, the tansparent view method didn't work. Quartz Event Taps seem to be the best answer.

Here are some hints on working with taps:

1. Create the tap with `CGEventTapCreate`.
   a) For the location (first) parameter you'll probably want to use `kCGSessionEventTap`.
   b) For the placement (second) parameter you'll probably want `kCGHeadInsertEventTap`.
   c) For the event mask parameter, try `(1 << kCGEventMouseMoved)`.
2. Create a run loop source with `CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource`, passing the event tap as the second parameter.
3. Add the run loop source to your run loop. Assuming you want it added to the main run loop, do:
   `CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetMain(), sourceFromStep2, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);`
4. Enable the event tap with `CGEventTapEnable`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand event taps a bit better now. I ended up using Ben's NSEvent method, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to track the mouse no matter where it is, you want a CGEventTap. There is no Cocoa equivalent. If you just want to track it in your application then you should explain why you're finding yourself unable to do so a little more thoroughly.

Comment: This did work perfectly for me, but Ben's answer was definitely exactly what I was looking for.