# Passing Click Through Transparent Window

Tags: macos, cocoa, click, nswindow, objective-c-2.0

I have a fullscreen transparent window. When the user clicks on it I want the click to be sent  to what's underneath the window. How would I do so?

Comment: if googling for iOS ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451902/294884

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting IgnoresMouseEvents to YES should do the trick..

- (void)setIgnoresMouseEvents:(BOOL)ignoreMouseEvents

Specifies whether the window is transparent to mouse clicks and other mouse events, allowing overlay windows.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setIgnoresMouseEvents:

Comment: Thank you but there is a problem. If I set that property to YES not only the window ignores the mouse events, but the whole app does (I'm overriding `-sendEvent:` in an `NSApplication` subclass but it is not called on left mouse clicks anymore when I set `'setIgnoresMouseEvents'` to NO.

Comment: I solved that thanks to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628366/global-mouse-moved-events-in-cocoa