# How can i make a programmatically custom tooltip in cocoa (OS X)?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, tooltip

I need to make a custom tooltip view for all views of my project. This tooltip view has a specific shape (pentagon), font, font color and background color. Also it should has a typically delay, like  the system tooltip, when mouse enter and mouse exit from view. Which is the best way for do this?

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to make a custom tooltip view for all views of my project.

For **all** views? Most applications have a lot of views that the user isn't even aware of — views used to contain groups of controls and such. So it'd be strange to offer tool tips for every view. Tool tips are usually used with interface components that actually *do* something, and their purpose is to tell the user what that something is. That's why you see that `NSControl` has methods for managing tool tips, but `NSView` doesn't.

> Which is the best way for do this?

First, decide whether you really mean that you want tool tips for every view, or if you actually just want the same kind of tool tips that Cocoa already offers, but drawn differently. If the latter, then you could subclass each type of control you use and override [`draw(withExpansionFrame:in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428895-draw) to draw the kind of tool tips you want.

If you really want tool tips for every view, you might do better to implement your own system. One approach might be to have some object in your app [monitor mouse moved events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1632343/643383). You can start a timer to track elapsed time after each mouse moved event, with each new event invalidating the old timer and starting a new one. If the timer expires, it can add a view displaying your pentagonal "tool tip" view to the window near the mouse.

Comment: I subclassed NSButton, but the "draw(withExpansionFrame:in:)" is not getting called, even though button has "toolTip" property set.

Comment: You also need to override `expansionFrame(withFrame:)` and return a valid rect there for the method to be called.